# Why does not multi-threads save time in my Python script?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following script which utilizes threading module in order to save time when doing cycle.

```
import threading, time, sys 

def cycle(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        pass

#########################################################
thread1 = threading.Thread(target = cycle, args=(1,1000000))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target = cycle, args=(1000001,2000000))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
print 'start join'
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
print 'end join'
```

However, I found the the script cost even more time than the one without multi-threads (`cycle(1, 2000000)`).

What might be the reason and how can I save time?

Comment: the reason is the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). python threads would not help you if your tasks are CPU bound

Comment: @shx2 not necessarily, I wonder how did the OP benchmarked it...

Answer (score 1):

Threads are often not useful in Python because of the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock):  only one thread can run Python code at a time.

There are cases where the GIL doesn't cause much of a bottleneck, e.g. if your threads are spending most of their time calling thread-safe native (non-Python) functions, but your program doesn't appear to be one of those cases.  So even with two threads, you're basically running just one thread at a time, plus there's the overhead of two threads contending for a lock.